# Why people advice to use Riseup.net and SecurityKISS VPN?

Tags: anonymity, vpn, deanonymization, openvpn

As I see here people always advice to use Riseup.net VPN or SecurityKISS. I just want to ask why people here advice soo much to use that 2 vpns and what are their pros compared to other VPN's. As I know VPN can not use any exploit to look what Tor user is doing in Tor. Or this VPN's a better versus timing attacks ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about VPNs not Tor.

Comment: Also **no one here is advising anyone to use VPNs, infact I am [explicitly advising against it](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/misconception.md#vpns)**

Comment: Riseup and SecurityKISS are both very privacy concerned VPNs that don't log any of your data, making it great for security and anonymity.

Comment: No. VPNs provide no anonymity and privacy isn't security.

Comment: What are you talking about? The whole selling point of VPN's are to provide security & anonymity

Comment: VPNs provide confidentiality between two points. They provide no anonymity and no privacy and no security.